# Updating table in trigger after insert on the same table

Tags: mysql

i have create a trigger for update same table after insert data on the same table

hear is my code

```
BEGIN
SET @sub=(select core_1 from student_detail where roll_no=new.roll_no);
SET @crdt=(select credit from subject_entry where sub_name=@sub);
IF(new.total>89 && new.total<101) 
THEN
SET new.grade='O';
SET new.gp=10;
SET new.cp=@crdt;
END IF;
END
```

it throughs an error subquery return multiple row, while insert data on the table

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the values in the record being processed, then use a *before* update/insert trigger, not an *after* update.

That is probably all you need to do.